# Is there a way to properly invert the y-axis in Python's 3DAxes plot_surface without it interfering with the x-axis?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, 3d, surface

I'm using 3DAxes in Python to plot a surface plot. Im trying to manipulate the y-axis to go from [25 - 0] instead of going from [0-25] in the plot itself. So far I've tried to just use ax.invert_yaxis(), but my problem is that this changes the x-axis to have the same numerical values as the y-axis. My suspiscion is that this is because I use np.meshgrid earlier in the code.

Does anyone know how to invert just the y-axis?

**I have this:**

[image]

I want to change so the y-axis goes from 25 to 0, and naturally the surfaceplot will change as well then.

**But when I use invert_yaxis I get this:**

[image]

Which is wrong cause the x-axis is changed in numerically values as well...

**CODE:**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d

Tcm_0 = 17.9 #K

def t(T): 
    return T/Tcm_0
my_0 = 1.25663706212e-6
Hcm_0 = 29.7 / my_0 #A/m 

def Hc2(T): 
    return Hcm_0 * (1 - np.power(t(T),1.52))

def h(H, T): 
    return H/Hc2(T)

C_1 = 350e3 #AT/mm^2

def Jc(H, T): 
    return (C_1/(my_0*H))*(1 - np.power(t(T),1.52))*(1 - np.power(t(T),2))*np.power(h(H,T),0.5)*np.power(1-h(H,T),2)
    
    
fig = plt.figure()

ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')

T = np.linspace(0,17,100)

B = np.linspace(0.1,28,100)

H = B/my_0 


T, H = np.meshgrid(T,H)

J = Jc(H,T) 

B = H*my_0

surface = ax.plot_surface(T,B,J, cmap='winter', linewidth=0)

ax.set_xbound(0, Tcm_0)

ax.set_xlabel('Temperature [K]')

ax.set_ybound(0, Hcm_0*my_0)

ax.invert_yaxis() <- This us what I dont get to work.

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by manually setting the limits for the axis, no need to invert anything.

```
ax.set_ylim(25, 0)
```